# Service like for one bundle in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, service, dbal

I'm trying to create a model class (which will use DBAL), and i'd like to use it like a service in my bundle.

I've tried to create a service with this configuration in my bundle :

```
services:
   X:
     class:        X
     arguments:   [@database_connection]
```

But the fact is i don't want to configure this service in app/config/config.yml because it will only be used in one bundle.

Is there any way to create a specific bundle service, and giving **@database_connection**  parameter to the class ? Or am i forced to configure it for all my app ?

My goal here is only to have distinct class for my controller and my model, without using the Doctrine ORM/Entity, just the DBAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every bundle has his own config files.

```
# src/Acme/YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    X:
       class:        X
       arguments:   [@database_connection]
```

The bundle configuration is loaded trough the DIC. So this file in your bundle is important

```php
// src/Acme/YourBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeYourBundleExtension.php

namespace Acme\YourBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class AcmeYourExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Generally, you should configure all services in the bundle specific `services.yml` and not in `config.yml`. So you can reuse them. But the service is visible for the complete application not only for the bundle. But this should be no problem.